# How to load a client-script from browserify that exposes module.exports (via jadeify)

Tags: javascript, express, requirejs, pug, browserify

I have a javascript file created from a jade template with [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) + [browserify-middleware](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/browserify-middleware) + [jadeify](https://github.com/domenic/jadeify)

That's all on the server side in node, this is the only thing needed to make it create the generated javascript file:

```
app.use('/templates', require('browserify-middleware')('./public-includes'),
{
    grep: /\.jade$/,
    transform: ['jadeify']
}));
```

Then in the web browser, I get some javascript code from `/templates/template.jade`, (**EDIT:** I posted it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qg83w/1/)) I can see it sets all kinds of functions on module.exports (just like node). But how do I use it from the client side? I tried with `require.js` like this `var template = require('/templates/template.jade', function(template){});`, which returned undefined.

Should I use browserify on the client-side as well? All the examples I've seen talk about bundles and stuff, but I don't know if it applies, I run it on a directory and don't provide a bundle name anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, use browserify everywhere.  To do this, just have an `client.js` file which does:

```
var template = require('./templates/template.jade');
// rest of code here
```

Then on the server, do:

```
app.get('/client.js', require('browserify-middleware')('./client.js',
{
    transform: ['jadeify']
}));
```

In your html you then just do:

```
<script src="/client.js"></script>
```

An alternative, if you want to use something like requirejs or just a standalone global you can do:

```
app.get('/templates', require('browserify-middleware')('./public-includes'),
{
    grep: /\.jade$/,
    transform: ['jadeify'],
    standalone: 'template'
}));
```

You should then find either a global `template` variable is declared on the client, or it should work with requirejs so you can do something like:

```
require('/templates/template.jade', function (template) {
  //use template here
});
```

I'm not very experienced with requirejs though, so your milage may vary with that approach.  I really recommend using browserify for everything.

Comment: you've demonstrated my exact problem with all this approach, I don't understand - in my code example browserify is pointed at a directory (which makes sense to me) and individual files become javascript wrappers. with your `client.js` example I would need to create a reference to each template in that directory? In your second example - what is `standalone` if it runs on a directory? does it name every file and puts that in the global scope?

Comment: Sorry sorry, just adding `standalone: 'template'` names the function - which is not actually needed because it is returned by require.js, but it also makes the whole thing work. Thanks, I'm very relieved to see this working :)

Comment: I'm still uncertain about the global scope and how it would work with `standalone` and a directory, but since it works for me with require.js, I'm not sure I care.

Comment: The problem with using `standalone` with a directory is that, as it currently stands, it would name every global the same.  For require.js the name is not relevant, so you can name it whatever you want, but if you just included it with a `<script>` tag you'd get a variable called `template` and that variable would be overridden if you loaded a second template.

Comment: Thanks so much for following up. That's how I assumed it worked, as long as there's a way to make it work, I'm happy